# Error :Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::fill() must be of the type array

Tags: php, ajax, laravel-5

Deseo realizar la actualización del registro en un solo campo de la tabla mediante ajax de la siguiente manera:

```
$('#cerrar').click(function(){
 var registro=$('#cerrar').val();  
 var route="http://127.0.0.1:8000/almacen/compras/"+registro;
 var token=$("input[name=_token]").val();
 $.ajax({  
  url:route,
  headers:{'X-CSRF-TOKEN':token},
  type:'PUT',
  dataType:'json',
  data:{ 
    estado:2
  },
  success:function(){
    alert('correcto');
  }

});
```

});

donde la función del controlador se encuentra así:

```
public function cerrar(Request $request, $id){
    $compra=compra::find($id);
    $compra->fill($request->input('estado'))->save();

    return response()->json([
         "mensaje"=>"Actualizacion de registro correcto." 
    ]);

}
```

Pero el servidor me da como respuesta

> Type error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::fill() must be of the type array

Comment: prueba primero a poner un var_dump($request->input('estado')); a ver que te devuelve. por lo que dice el mensaje tienes que mandar un array, y ese elemento del var_dump no lo es.

Comment: pero como vería la respuesta del var_dump si la petición la hago por el método PUT y los datos para actualizar por json

Comment: la forma en que pasas los datos al método fill() deben ser en forma de array asociativo es decir clave => valor, algo mas o menos así

Comment: $compra->fill(array('estado' => $request->input('estado'));

Comment: no estoy seguro si te acepte el segundo parametro o la clave sin comillas así que también prueba poniendoselas así

Comment: $compra->fill(array('estado' => '$request->input('estado')');   o con comillas dobles                                    $compra->fill(array('estado' => "$request->input('estado')");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El aviso que te aparece te indica que el método fill requiere los valores que le vas a pasar en forma de array asociativo; es decir

```
$valores = array('clave1' => 'valor1', 'clave2' => 'valor2');
```

Por lo tanto lo puedes manejar del siguiente modo:

```
$compra->fill(array('estado' => $request->input('estado')));
```

Comment: Funciono correctamente gracias a tu ayuda  pese a que al final le faltaba un ')', funciono a la perfeccion muchisimas gracias Alfredo Paz